# A component managing the rendering of another on the same level

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code:

```
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
       <ul>
         <li><a onClick={() => this.props.onViewChange('home')}>Home</a></li>
         <li><a onClick={() => this.props.onViewChange('login')}>Login</a></li>
         <li><a onClick={() => this.props.onViewChange('register')}>Register</a></li>
         <li><a onClick={() => this.props.onViewChange('profile')}>Profile</a></li>
       </ul>
    )
  }
}


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = ({ view: "home" })
  }

    render()
    {
       return (
         <div className="app">
           <Header onViewChange={(view) => this.setState({ view: view })} />
           <Main view={this.state.view} />
         </div>
       )
    }
}

class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = { view: props.view }
    }

    render() {
      switch (this.state.view) {
        case "home":
          return <Home />
        case "login":
          return <Login />
        case "register":
          return <Register />
        case "profile":
          return <Profile />
      }
   }
}
```

As you can see, I have an `<App />` that contains a `<Header />` and a `<Main />`.

`<Main>` manages which view is being rendered, and `<Header />` has the navigation that changes the current view. The way that this code is written will only work, if I add a `componentWillReceiveProps` to `<Main />` but I read that it is an anti pattern, and it is even being deprecated.

What would be a better way to manage this situation?

**Notes:**

- I am not using React Router or Redux for the time being. I would like to know how should be done in vanilla React
- I know I could manage which view is rendered directly in `<App />`. This is just a simplified version of my problem, and my interest lies in knowing how to pass information between components that live in the same level.
- I would like to find a solution that would allow me to control the view from multiple places, even from inside the same `Main` component

Comment: Your code is right, except that you shouldn't duplicate props into state in `Main`. There's no benefit to doing that. Copying props into state is usually an anti-pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be just like this:

```
class Main extends Component {


    render() {
      switch (this.props.view) {
        case "home":
          return <Home />
        case "login":
          return <Login />
        case "register":
          return <Register />
        case "profile":
          return <Profile />
      }
   }
}
```

You can also pass a callback to `<Main/>` which would change view state in `<App/>`. In such case view state would only live in one place, namely in `<App/>`, and you would not have to duplicate it inside `<Main/>` as you are doing right now. Because duplicating state is normally not advised and that is what causes the need for `componentWillReceiveProps` which as you noted is anti pattern.

Comment: But then, if I wanted to change the view from inside `Main`, I wouldnt be able to do it, no? (I should have included that in the question. I will add it)

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent Why not, you could. Just pass callbacks to `Main` which change view state inside `App`, isn't it?

Comment: You mean to pass a method to `Main` to control the state upwards? Like this? `<Main changeView={(view) => this.setState({view: view)}>`

Comment: What if, inside Main, I want to change the view AND some other Main-bound state? Should I call both, the callback, and `setState` one after the other?

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent I am not sure what you mean but if  you want to change state in parent one way is that parent passes callback to child, as you have with App and header now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173949/discussion-between-enrique-moreno-tent-and-giorgim).